# $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Proof $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic.

My intuition is that there are four generators in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}: 1 \times 1, 1 \times -1, -1 \times 1, -1 \times -1$. And the group they generated are $(z,z)$ or $(z,-z)$, rather than two independent $(z_1, z_2)$, where $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

But is this the right way to think about it, and right way to write it? Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You’re attempting the impossible. The subgroup generated by $\langle m,n\rangle\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ is $$\{\langle mk,nk\rangle:k\in\Bbb Z\}\;;$$ can you find **any** pair $\langle m,n\rangle\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ for which this set is all of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Ah, I got it. It is so clear, thank you very much Brain!

Comment: @Tumbleweed: You’re very welcome.

Comment: And I like the way you lead me there!

Comment: @Tumbleweed: Thanks! I try to give good hints, but sometimes it’s hard to come up with one.

Comment: Very nicely explained, it requires to know that $x^n = n*x$ for $\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 5):

Any quotient of a cyclic group is cyclic but $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a non-cyclic quotient of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$ is *not* cyclic. You've correctly realized that if it *were* cyclic, then its generator would have to have a very specific form; but it's routine to see that none of the elements you've listed is a generator.

---

For a more formal way of writing, suppose that some $(a, b)$ were a generator. It's clear that $|a| \le 1$ and $|b| \le 1$ (else, we'd miss elements of the form $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$). It's also clear that $a \ne 0$ and $b \ne 0$.

Now note that $(a, -b) \notin \langle (a, b) \rangle$ and we're done.